# ¿Se puede llamar a un objeto desde el evento onclick?

Tags: reactjs

Tengo un objeto `li` y quiero crear un objeto desde su evento `onclick`. Lo que quiero es poder crear un objeto desde el evento `click` del `list item`.

¿Se puede hacer? Si no se puede, ¿Hay alguna alternativa?

Ejemplo:

```
class Ejemplo extends Component{

    liclick(event){
        <Objeto2 name="hola"/>
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <li onClick={this.liclick.bind(this)}>
        )
    }
}

class Objeto2 extends Component{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render(){
        return(
            {this.props.name}
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Me autocontesto. El único sitio donde se renderizan los objetos es en el método render. Lo que se puede hacer es un estado que se active al clicar con el botón. De la siguiente manera...

```
class Ejemplo extends Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    showComponent:false,
  };
 }

  liclick(event){
     this.setState({
       showComponent:true,
    });
  }
  render(){
    return(
        <div>
        <li onClick={this.liclick.bind(this)}>
        {this.state.showComponent ? <Chart symbol=   {this.props.stock.symbol}/> : null}
        <div>
    )
  }
}

class Objeto2 extends Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render(){
    return(
        {this.props.name}
    )
  }
}
```